# How to step forward while a systemcall hasn't returned a value

Tags: python, linux

Suppose I call the `su` command via python's `os.system("su")` and after entering root mode I want python to execute a list of commands in this freshly entered root/superuser mode..how do I get a premature return value without exiting the root mode ?

Comment: You could use the `pexpect` module.

Comment: Alternatively use `subprocess.Popen` and check the stderr and stdout streams.

Comment: @Blender am checking out the pexpect library ..looks promising.